# Visualizar archivos pdf en Laravel

Tags: html5, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo archivos pdf ya subidos al servidor, los cargo en una lista y deseo poder mostrarlos al usuario, pero para todos los enlaces siempre me muestra el primero que subí.

Lo que envío desde el controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $documentos = Documento::paginate();
    return view('Documentos.index',compact('documentos'));
}
```

Lo que muestra la vista:

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead class="text-center">
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="col-md-3">Titulo</th>
            <th class="col-md-2" colspan="2">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($documentos as $item)
            <tr class="row">
                <td class="col-md-3 text-center">{{ $item->titulo }}</td>
                <td class="col-md-2 text-center">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" title="Ver documento" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Mostrar PDF</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{-- Modal --}}
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <embed src="{{asset('archivos/'.$item->ruta)}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Sólo me carga el primer documento que subí en todos los enlaces, donde debería mostrar documentos distintos.
Ayuda comunidad.

Comment: Hola. ¿Has revisado en BD si para el campo *ruta* se guardaron los distintos valores?

Comment: Si mi estimado, en BD se están guardando correctamente, volví a revisar y soló me muestra el primero que subí en todos los enlaces de la lista.

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la paginación pasándole un parámetro y pasarle la variable $documentos:

```
public function index() {
    $documentos = Documento::paginate(10);
    return view('Documentos.index')->with('documentos', $documentos);
}
```

Y así se verían diez elementos

Answer (score 1):

Es simple, asignas `data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg"` y tienes el modal con la clase: `class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg"`.

Y siempre abrirá el ultimo, ya que no tienes un identificador único; te recomiendo cambiar el data target:

```
data-target="#modalpdf_{{$item->id}}"
```

Y colocar un id en cada modal:

```
id="modalpdf_{{$item->id}}"
```

Y asi tendrás **N** modals con identificadores unicos, con eso deberias de solucionar tu problema.

**Recomendacion:** Imagina que cargar solo 10 datos con paginate, y que cada pdf  tenga un peso de 5MB, tu pagina tendria que cargar 50MB para poder mostrarte el resultado, es algo muy, muy malo. Deberias de ver la forma de cargarlo con **ajax** o algo asi.